# C equivalent of Python ranges for loops

Tags: python, c, arrays, range, intersection

I have only recently started coding in C, and I was seeing if there is a standard implementation (preferably without using additional libraries) of union of non-exclusive ranges, like in Python.

I am looking for the C equivalent of the following (in Python):

```
for k in (range(-1, 2) + range(i-1, i+2)):
```

It does not suffice to define an array containing elements with these ranges, because depending on the intersection of the two ranges (which depends on i), the size of the array. What is my best option here?

Comment: I don't think this workswith Python 3.

Comment: in case you want to avoid iterating twice, you should edit the python code in the question to something like `for k in (range(-1, 2) + (range(i-1, i+2) if i>1 else []))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two loops:

```
for (k = -1; k < 2; ++k) {
  do_stuff(k);
}
for (k = i - 1; k < i + 2; ++k) {
  do_stuff(k);
}
```

Alternatively, in C99:

```
int indices[] = {-1, 0, 1, i - 1, i, i + 1};
for (int j = 0; j < 6; ++j) {
  int k = indices[j];
  // ...
}
```

The question says:

> depending on the intersection of the two ranges (which depends on i), the size of the array.

This isn't how the code in the question works. If the two ranges intersect, the code iterates over the intersecting values twice. The C code presented here mimics that.

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't really work, though, because, in case of intersecting ranges, I would be running over the intersecting values twice. I'd like to take into account the possibility of the ranges intersecting (for i = 0 or i = 1, for instance)

Comment: @SulfoCyaNate: Well, the code in your question *does* iterate over the intersecting ranges twice, and so does the code in this answer.